# Setting a client certificate as a request property in a Java HTTP connection?

Tags: java, url, https, certificate

I have a Java application that connects to another Java app through a socket with SSL, so my client JVM already has the `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` properties set.

This application needs to make some HTTP requests to a web server that requires client authentication. I can open the connection by using a `URLConnection` in Java which returns an `HTTPSURLConnectionImpl`.

The client certificate I want to present to the web server in the request is different than the one set as my JVM system property. Is there a way I can set a client cert. as a request property in the `HTTPSURLConnectionImpl` ?

Comment: It wouldn't be sufficient to send it in an HTTP header. It wouldn't securely identify you. You have to send it via the SSL mechanism, so that the other SSL steps associated with it are performed, so as to provide secure authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a SSL "client certificate" is not adequate directly through `HTTPSURLConnectionImpl`'s request properties, because a digital signature is also required to prove you own the certificate. SSL already does all that automatically, so to makes sense to use that layer.

You have two ways to solve your issue going forward.

### Through configuration

You can add you client key and certificate to your JVM KeyStore, it should be picked up at Runtime when the server asks for your client-side SSL authentication. (SSL/TLS is designed for that : the server will ask for a client certificate that is signed by it's trusted authority, which allows the SSL Engine to choose the right certificate, even when your KeyStore holds many).

### Through Code

You can roll you own `SSLContext` using custom made `KeyStore`/`TrustStore`s.
This is a bit complex (I won't elaborate on how to build `Keystore` instances in Java), but the gist of it is here :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

KeyStore clientKeyStore = ... // Whatever
KeyStore clientTrustStore = ... // Whatever you need to load

// We build the KeyManager (SSL client credentials we can send)
KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyFactory.init(clientKeyStore, "password".toCharArray());
KeyManager[] km = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();

// We build the TrustManager (Server certificates we trust)
TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustFactory.init(clientTrustStore);
TrustManager[] tm = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();

// We build a SSLContext with both our trust/key managers
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(km, tm, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSf = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

// We prepare a URLConnection 
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
// Before actually opening the sockets, we affect the SSLSocketFactory
HttpsURLConnection httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection;
httpsUrlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSf);

// Ready to go !
}
```

Comment: It's possible but insufficient, and a client certificate is not a secret key, otherwise good answer.

Comment: thanks. rolling my own SSLContext turned out to be the right approach for me and allows for some flexibility.

Comment: Can you please publish and share your final solution?