# SSL Check bypass - SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to bypass the SSL check for for my connection - SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

All the examples (like [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)) I've seen so far are for HTTPClient. Can anyone shed some light on how to acheive the same for SSLSocketFactory as well? I'm trying to make a SSL connection with my secure server.

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883632/setting-a-client-certificate-as-a-request-property-in-a-java-http-conneciton/28883926#28883926 where I provide a set up for HTTPURLConnection. Mix & matching both should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

i would not use "SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();" in my example you see how you get an sslSocket that does not check any certificate. But i can not suggest to

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager;

class AnyTrust extends X509ExtendedTrustManager {
    static final X509Certificate[] ANY_CA = {};
    @Override public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return ANY_CA; }
    @Override public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] c, final String t)  {}
    @Override public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] c, final String t)  { }
    @Override public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] c, final String t, final SSLEngine e)  { }
    @Override public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] c, final String t, final Socket    e)  { }
    @Override public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] c, final String t, final SSLEngine e)  { }
    @Override public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] c, final String t, final Socket    e)  { }
}

public class S1 {
    public static final void main(final String [] argc) throws Throwable {
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new AnyTrust()}, null);
        final SSLSocketFactory sslsocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
}
```